# How to allow only authorised admin to use the "Edit", "Page" Ribbon in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jquery, ribbon, authorization

[image: Ribbon image]

I'm trying to make the Ribbon such that only authorized admin (permissions set in the site permissions feature) can use the Ribbon controls (Browse, Edit, Page). How do I prevent unauthorized users from using the ribbon? I'm currently using SharePoint 2013. Is the solution to this issue under site settings? Or maybe I have to use javascript? Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use SPSecurityTrimmedControl for this.

```
<!—MS:<SharePoint:SpSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server" permission="permission needed to access">—>
the content you want to hide
<!—MS:</SharePoint:SpSecurityTrimmedControl>—>
```

Some sample threads for your reference.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/vinitt/2013/04/27/hide-ribbon-for-anonymous-users-sharepoint-2013/

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-add-a-security-trim-snippet-in-sharepoint

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cae6509f-7835-4f7b-bdcd-ee445c4dfbf9/disable-master-page-ribbon-for-certain-sp-groups?forum=sharepointgeneralprevious

Comment: This solution works to a certain extent. It does disable the ribbon but causes my UI's scrollbar to be gone, and I can't scroll down the page. Is there any alternatives to display:block? I tried display:none it doesn't work either.

Comment: Without the css, the scrollbar is still non-existent

Answer (score 0):

**Is the solution to this issue under site settings?**

Unfortunately, No.

**Or maybe I have to use javascript?**

No need to use JS, just follow the below steps to hide the ribbon from the non-admin users

**Steps**

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- Open your site > From left side Click on Master Pages.
- In SharePoint 2013 There are two related files for Master Page (HTML, Master)
- Right Click on your custom Master Page with **HTML extension** > Check Out.
- Again, Right Click on Master Page with HTML extension > Edit File Advanced Mode.
- Search for DIV with ID `“ms-designer-ribbon“`
- Surround it with this tag `SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl` to looks the following

> ```
> <!--MS:<SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl runat="server"  
> PermissionsString="FullMask">-->
> < div id="ms-designer-ribbon" >
>  <!--SID:02 {شريط}-->
>  <!--PS:  -->
>
>
> <!--PE:  -->
> </div>
> <!--ME:</SharePoint:SPSecurityTrimmedControl>-->
> ```

- In PermissionsString attribute, you can add any permission type based on your requirement from the following:

  - FullMask.
  - EmptyMask.
  - ManagePermissions.
  - ManageSubwebs.
  - ManageWeb.
  - AddAndCustomizePages.
  - BrowseDirectories.
  - ViewPages.
  - EnumeratePermissions.
  - ManageAlerts.
- Save the changes > Check In > Publish Master Page as a major version.

Check the detail steps at [How to hide the SharePoint 2013 ribbon](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/03/12/hide-ribbon-sharepoint-2013-using-css/)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70548/discussion-on-answer-by-m-qassas-how-to-allow-only-authorised-admin-to-use-the).